# Cross Compile arp-scan for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, libpcap

I am trying to cross compile arp-scan for ARM based platform.
Since arp-scan has dependency on pcap, first of all pcap was cross compiled and installed at a directory `/usr/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi`.

Again on trying to cross compile arp-scan the steps followed are

```
cd arp-scan
autoreconf --install
./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/usr/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi --libdir=/usr/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-uclibcgnueabi/include.
```

The configuration failed with error message

```
configure: Cannot find pcap library containing pcap_open_live
configure: error: Check that you have libpcap version 1.0 or later installed
```

Can anyone suggest what is the issue in the given configuration and how to link the pcap library in the configuration options for cross compilation

Comment: The configure part cannot find the library. Is it installed? 
Else try to install it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/568859/error-pcap-library-not-found

Comment: It is installed in x86 machine.I want to know how to link the  pcap library  cross compiled for arm to arp-scan configuration. The link mentioned above works fine for x86 not for ARM.